# How to do joins in SequelizeJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

This is my model definition of Room table

```
sequelize.define("room", {
 id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
 name: DataTypes.STRING,
 business_id: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  references: {
    model:"business,
    key: "id"
  }
 }
});
```

And this is of business

```
sequelize.define("business", {
 id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
 name: DataTypes.STRING,
});
```

Now consider I have `id` of the room with me and I want to get business related to that using the foreign key. In normal `SQL` I would easily do this using `inner join`

I know that there is something like Association used in Sequelize but then what is the use of defining a reference in the model definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the **[DOC](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#enforcing-a-foreign-key-reference-without-constraints)** :

> Sometimes you may want to reference another table, without adding any
>   constraints, or associations. In that case you can manually add the
>   reference attributes to your schema definition, and mark the relations
>   between them.

**[Association :](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/base.js~Association.html)**

> Creating associations in sequelize is done by calling one of the
>   belongsTo / hasOne / hasMany / belongsToMany functions on a model (the
>   source), and providing another model as the first argument to the
>   function (the target).
>
> 1. hasOne - adds a foreign key to the target and singular association
>      mixins to the source.
> 2. belongsTo - add a foreign key and singular association mixins to the source.
> 3. hasMany - adds a foreign key to target and plural association mixins to the source.
> 4. belongsToMany - creates an N:M association with a join table and adds plural association mixins to the source. The junction table is
>      created with sourceId and targetId.
>
> Creating an association will add a foreign key constraint to the
>   attributes. All associations use CASCADE on update and SET NULL on
>   delete, except for n:m, which also uses CASCADE on delete.

I think this will clear your doubts.

Comment: Thank you. In the first case, how should I access related tables data?

Comment: @Praveena ,I think for that you have to use association , as refernce is just to define Pk and Fk relation , and checks for that each time data inserts/or updates ,  Still you can try with include , but I dont think it will work

Comment: It didn't work with include :-) so got confused thinking what is the use of creating a reference in the model definition.

Comment: Its just for validating PK FK relation , and define it with model as it will throw error if something unrelated got inserted or updated

Comment: Then I can completely remove that from model and go ahead with creating association rt? Like Room.belongsTo(Business)

Comment: @Praveena , yes that's the standard way to do it. :)

Comment: One more doubt. In this section of the first link you provided `Enforcing a foreign key reference without constraints` they are creating the reference in the model also and creating association also, why is that so?

Comment: To get data via include , in association FK is added automatically to table , so to prevent that , they have used rerence for enforce foreign key and use association to get data via include

Comment: I am so sorry bro, didn't understand the last comment. Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: `Creating an association will add a foreign key constraint to the attributes. All associations use CASCADE on update and SET NULL on delete, except for n:m, which also uses CASCADE on delete.` to prevent this reference is used